# How can I validate multiply input values at the same time using onkeyup before activating the submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to create a form where the submit button is disabled until the form is ready to be submitted. Not only does the form need to be filled in, but certain parameters need to be met. Passwords must match. Email must be valid and not already be in the database. A radio button must be selected. How can I send the values from all inputs at the same time on every upkey.

Here's my index.php file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate_form(value){
            $.post("validate_form.php",{first_name:value},function(data){
                if (data=="Available"){
                    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
                }
            });
        }; 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="validate_form(first_name.value)"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password_repeat" placeholder="Re-enter Password"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Y" id="yes">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="N" id="no">No
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" disabled id="mySubmit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my validate_form.php file

```
<?php

    $first_name = "";
    $last_name = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    $password_repeat = "";
    $answer = "";
    $go = array(0,0,0,0,0);

    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];}
    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];}
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email = $_POST['email'];}
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){$password = $_POST['password'];}
    if(isset($_POST['password_repeat'])){$password_repeat = $_POST['password_repeat'];}
    if(isset($_POST['choice'])){$answer = $_POST['answer'];}    

    //Does email already exist in database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $loop = mysql_query($strSQL);   
    $email_exists = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)) {
        if($row['email'] == $email){
            $email_exists = 1;
        }
    }

    //Is email valid

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $email_valid = 1;
    } else {
        $email_valid = 0;
    }

    //Check each parameter

    if(strlen($first_name) > 0){
        $go[0] = 1;
    }
    if(strlen($last_name) > 0){
        $go[1] = 1;
    }
    if($email_exists != 1 and $email_valid == 1){
        $go[2] = 1;
    }
    if(strlen($password) > 6 and $password == $password_repeat){
        $go[3] = 1;
    }
    if($answer != ""){
        $go[4] = 1;
    }

    if(array_sum($go) == 5){
        echo "Available";
    } else {
        echo "Form is not viable";
    } 

?>
```

I currently have it send $first_name to validate_form.php, but I'm not sure how to send all variables at once. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: The question doesn't really make a lot of sense if you think about it. Why would you need to validate multiple fields at the same time based on a keyup event in a __single__ field? Also, as far as how you send multiple values via AJAX, that's a [RTFM answer](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) unfortunately. Here's a hint, it's no different than what you're doing now. You just add more values to your object `{first_name:value,another:value2,yetanother:value3,...}`

Comment: I want to output to the user in real time when their passwords match, and when their email is valid. Wouldn't I need to get both password fields at the same time to validate whether they are the same? How would you recommend doing this? I'm not great a javascript, so I'd love to heard suggestions.

Comment: What's the point in doing that? Just let them submit the form. You want to check the password while they're still in the middle of typing it? What sense does that make?

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner if all submissions were successful, which would require me to validate while they type. But you are right that it's not necessary. I've seen other websites do this, and I thought it might be fun in implement it myself.

Comment: Oh, you mean validate for registration? I thought you're talking about for login. Sure you can do that. You don't need to talk to your PHP backend though. You can just do it in javascript. Check for valid email, minimum password length, etc... There are like a trillion and one results for that on Google. Plenty of javascript libraries for form validation too. Just do some searching.

Comment: Thanks. And I've had a lot more experience with php then javascript so I was just trying to use a language I was more familiar with. I have seen a lot of examples of javascript validating forms, but none that actually check a database to see if the email address already exists, so that made me think I would need php. I'll keep looking though. Thanks for the input.